# How to debug crash during spritekit rendering?

Tags: crash, sprite-kit, render

I'm making an IOS game using spritekit, and also integrated crashlytics for error reporting.  I'm receiving the following error report periodically, and I'm unable to reproduce it, and unsure how to even start going about finding the problem.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.spritekit.renderQueue
0  SpriteKit                      0x2faed240 SKCShapeSprite::_NEW_copyRenderPathData(SKRenderQuad*, bool) const + 711
1  ???                            0x0061b9d0 
2  SpriteKit                      0x2fb12d09 SKCShapeSprite::copyRenderPathData(SKRenderQuad*, bool) + 40
3  SpriteKit                      0x2fb0fdbd SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float, unsigned int&, bool) + 428
4  SpriteKit                      0x2fb10987 SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float, unsigned int&, bool) + 3446
5  SpriteKit                      0x2fb10987 SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float, unsigned int&, bool) + 3446
6  SpriteKit                      0x2fb0b0d7 SKCRenderer::preprocessAndSubmitSpriteInternal(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo const*, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo const*> >&, std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&) + 94
7  SpriteKit                      0x2fb0f94f SKCRenderer::preprocessAndSubmitSprite(SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&) + 154
8  SpriteKit                      0x2fb0da69 SKCRenderer::submitScene(SKScene*, bool) + 524
9  SpriteKit                      0x2fb11ba9 SKCRenderer::renderScene(SKScene*, bool) + 152
10 SpriteKit                      0x2faa95f7 -[SKView _renderContent] + 1102
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a3758b7 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a37cb69 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 48
13 SpriteKit                      0x2faa917b -[SKView renderContent] + 82
14 SpriteKit                      0x2faa5f15 __29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 116
15 SpriteKit                      0x2fad7509 -[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 248
16 QuartzCore                     0x2f679aa3 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 98
17 QuartzCore                     0x2f67990b CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 366
18 IOMobileFramebuffer            0x33f2e82b IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 90
19 IOKit                          0x2d68c801 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 256
20 CoreFoundation                 0x2c71d8e5 __CFMachPortPerform + 132
21 CoreFoundation                 0x2c72ddab __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
22 CoreFoundation                 0x2c72dd47 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
23 CoreFoundation                 0x2c72c349 __CFRunLoopRun + 1608
24 CoreFoundation                 0x2c67a621 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
25 CoreFoundation                 0x2c67a433 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
26 GraphicsServices               0x33a290a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
27 UIKit                          0x2fc65359 UIApplicationMain + 1440
```